# Check significance of variable before loading in neural network

Tags: regression, neural-networks, statistical-significance, recurrent-neural-network

I'm programming a recurrent neural network that is supposed to predict inflation. Now given the huge amount of variables that could predict it, I thought it might be useful, to check significance in an OLS regression beforehand (at least in the test run, to go easy on my PC). Is it bad practice to use information of a statistical model on a black box model, or could one do that?

Greetings,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neural network will normally use the variable in a very different way from OLS regression, meaning that the (non-)significance in OLS regression will not be very informative about whether the variable will help in your neural net.

Comment: An example is if the variable has a quadratic relationship with the outcome, which the OLS model will miss (assume a symmetric parabola).